# MVVMLight RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged don't raise the CanExecuteChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm developing an application in WPF, with MVVMLight framework.

I'm trying to make unit tests (i'm novice in that). So I try to simulate my view by subscribing to the CanExecuteChanged event on my command and verify that it is correctly called. But when I do that it is never called, even if I call the RaiseCanExecuteChanged method.

Here is a very simple sample:

```
bool testCanExec = false;
var testCmd = new RelayCommand(
                     execute:    () => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Execute call"); },
                     canExecute: () => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CanExecute call"); return testCanExec; }
                );
testCmd.CanExecuteChanged += ((sender, args) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CanExecuteChanged call"); });
testCanExec = true;
testCmd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); // <= nothing in output
testCmd.Execute(null);            // <= output: "CanExecute call", "Execute call"
```

What I really can't understand is that it seems to work with my button. I don't know how but it enables and disables properly.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RelayCommand`'s `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method simply calls `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` which has no effect in the context of a unit test: https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/b23c4d5bf6df654ad885be26ea053fb0efa04973/V3/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs

..because there are no controls that have subscribed to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event.

Also, you are generally not really supposed to write unit tests that test the functionality of a third-party framework. You should probably focus on testing your own custom functionality.

But if you want to test the `CanExecute` method, you should simply call it instead of raising the `CanExecuteChanged` event:

```
bool b = testCmd.CanExecute(null);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.In fact I didn't want to test the MVVMLight Framework, I just wanted to be sure the CanExecuteChanged event correctly raises because the CanExecute method uses many other properties so I have to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged method each time one of these field is changed.